# What does the "1" in the R formula "y ~ 1" mean?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to understand the code
written in the following discussion
(see [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Weights-in-binomial-glm-td1991249.html)):

```
library(boot) 
library(reshape) 
dataset <- data.frame(Person = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 10)), Success = c(rbinom(20, 1, 0.25), rbinom(10, 1, 0.75))) 
Aggregated <- cast(Person ~ ., data = dataset, value = "Success", fun = list(mean, length)) 

m0 <- glm(Success ~ 1, data = dataset, family = binomial) 
m1 <- glm(mean ~ 1, data = Aggregated, family = binomial, weights = length) 

inv.logit(coef(m0)) 
inv.logit(coef(m1))
```

I am confused as to what the `1` in the formula `Success ~ 1` means.
In the documentation for the [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html),
there is a description of the special symbol `.` in a formula
but there is not description of `1`,
except that `y ~ x - 1` means a line through the origin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most R regression packages, `y ~ 1` means "fit an intercept *only*".

So in the case of linear regression, this is exactly the same as `mean(y)`. For glm's, it depends on the link function.

Also, `y ~ x - 1` means "regress x on y, but leave out the intercept".

Answer (score 1):

That means intercept only model. You can use `model.matrix` to find out. Try the following codes:

```
library(boot) 
library(reshape) 
dataset <- data.frame(Person = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 10)), Success = c(rbinom(20, 1, 0.25), rbinom(10, 1, 0.75))) 
Aggregated <- cast(Person ~ ., data = dataset, value = "Success", fun = list(mean, length)) 

m0 <- glm(Success ~ 1, data = dataset, family = binomial) 
model.matrix(Success ~ 1, data = dataset)
```